# how to workaround a java image scaling bug

Tags: java, image-scaling

I've got a java servlet which is hitting this bug when down-scaling images...

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5101502

I'm trying to work out the best way to work around it and would appreciate any ideas from the community.

Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 3):

Image scaling with Java can be surprisingly complicated - I ran into lots of reproducable JVM crashes when doing batch processing, which are not related to your bug though. In the end I ended up using the external command line tool 'convert' from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), available for the relevant platforms. Simply call it with `Runtime.exec(.)` and the appropriate parameters. Might be even faster than a real Java solution, but this is certainly not a good solution for all apps.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) API. An example of how to scale an image using JAI can be found [here](http://archives.java.sun.com/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind9908&L=jai-interest&P=R14150).

Comment: It would be simpler to use ImageMagick.
It takes quite some times to learn JAI and to be able to write effective code with it.